# Why Spring @Autowired doesn't work in abstract class?

Tags: spring, kotlin, autowired

I am doing this way  in abstract class

```
@Autowired
lateinit var fileContract: FileContract
```

with error

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property fileContract has not been initialized
```

But the same works in regular class. Why?

Comment: Is your concrete subclass a `@Component` or some other Spring annotation? Is its package scanned at start-up?

Comment: it has two annotations: @Suppress("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
@Service

Comment: Can you show the class where you are using instance of `RegulationExtractor` class?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding `@Component` annotation to the abstract class that had the uninitialized field? We run into a similar problem, that sorted it for us.

Comment: I had the same problem and, unfortunately, this is the only way I could sort out the problem

Comment: This awnswer is the correct one despite it is not marked as so.

Answer (score 0):

You should use constructor injection and not field injection where possible. That also would solve your problem, because you do not need to autowire anything in your abstract class, but you just declare it as a constructor parameter:

```
abstract class AbstractExtractor(
    val fileContract: FileContract,
    val dictionaryContractImpl: DictionaryContractImpl,
    val regulationContractImpl: RegulationContractImpl
) {
 ...
}
```

Note that the above notation declares `fileContract`, `dictionaryContractImpl` and `regulationContractImpl` as constructor parameters, and at the same time (due to the `val` keyword) as a local property of the class `AbstractExtractor`. This means that it is not necessary to declare any additional variables for them inside the class.

Now, your subclass `RegulationExtractor` also needs to use constructor injection, so that it can pass the autowired values on to the constructor of the super class:

```
@Service
class RegulationExtractor(
    fileContract: FileContract,
    dictionaryContractImpl: DictionaryContractImpl,
    regulationContractImpl: RegulationContractImpl
) : AbstractExtractor(
    fileContract, 
    dictionaryContractImpl, 
    regulationContractImpl
) {
    ...
}
```

If you need any of the constructor parameters also in the `RegulationExtractor` class, you can add the `val` keyword like in `AbstractExtractor`.

It should not be necessary to add the `@Autowired` annotation here, but if you want, you can change the above code to

```
@Service
class RegulationExtractor @Autowired constructor(
...
```

Comment: I am not clearly understand. Please take a look at my concrete class https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/ac4fd61d3735ce90935ff09559053f1c#file-regulationextractor-kt

Comment: @CatherineIvanova I extended my answer.